# SQLAlchemy - condition on join fails with AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'selectable'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm running SQLAlchemy with Pyramid. I'm trying to run a query with a custom 'join' condition :

```
DBSession.query(A)\
        .outerjoin(A.b, B.a_id == A.id)\
        .all()
```

however the query fails the following error :

> AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'selectable'

The problem stems from the condition, as if I remove it, the query works :

```
DBSession.query(A)\
        .outerjoin(A.b)\
        .all()
```

I don't understand the problem, as I follow the syntax described in [the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) :

> q = session.query(User).join(Address, User.id==Address.user_id)

Does anyone see what's going on ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ok I saw it.
If you add a custom condition, the syntax is not `.outerjoin(A.b, ...)`, but rather `.outerjoin(B, ...)`

They should accept both, really

(and the error message could be *a little* more explicit)

Comment: You're a saint for answering your own question and saving a stranger hours 3 years later

Answer (score 4):

Another possible reason for this error is incorrect usage of explicit ON clause for the `join()`: explicit ON clause should be a single expression. So, if your intention is to use multiple filters in the ON clause, they should be combined with `and_`/`or_`. E.g., if you want to have an additional condition in the ON clause for the join:

```
query(A).join(B, A.b_id = B.id, A.x > N)  # WRONG!
query(A).join(B, and_(A.b_id = B.id, A.x > N))  # CORRECT
```

---

[Query.join() SQLA API doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) is very detailed itself, but somewhat vague in the summary (it says it is `join(*args, **kwargs)` which doesn't help a lot). Here is the summary of **some** of the correct possible uses for the `Query.join()`:

```
# declare the join using own field which leads to the related object:
query(A).join(A.b)


# declare the join using a class of the related mapper:
query(A).join(B)


# same as above (using related mapper class) but use explicit ON clause
# ON clause can be any/"complex" expression
query(A).join(B, A.b_id = B.id)
query(A).join(B, _and(A.b_id = B.id, ...))


# reverse the order of the join (useful to do a right outer join for example):
query(A).select_entity_from(B).join(A, isouter=True)
```

In all examples above except for the first one:

- with an explicit ON clause both `A` and `B` can be not only mapper classes, but anything "selectable": `subquery()`, an instance of `Table` or an alias (`aliased(selectable)`) will do.
- without explicit ON clause `A` and `B` can be only a mapper class or a `Table` instance

Comment: I needed to use `and_` in my case. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of saying this is that if you are already specifying the relationship via `.outerjoin(A.b...`, you no longer need to specify the condition, and in fact cannot do both.

Answer (score 0):

For me I got this issue once I tried to `PATCH` a row in my db, I took the code directly from the  [SqlAlchemy2 doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update) and I tried to adapt it

```py
from sqlalchemy import update as sqlalchemy_update

query = sqlalchemy_update(DimensionsEvaluation).where(
                DimensionsEvaluation.id == id).values(DimensionsEvaluation.selected == True)
```

but I got this error:

```
Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'items'
```

to fix this I had simply to use dictionary for `values` like so

```py
    query = sqlalchemy_update(DimensionsEvaluation).where(
                DimensionsEvaluation.id == id).values({
                    "selected": True
                })
```

check this link for more details https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sqlalchemy-core-update-statement/